# Can't find REST resource

Tags: java, rest, web

So i'm trying to develop web app which has Java Class names "Service.java" which is my REST Service.

```
@Path("/service")
public class Service {

    @Context
    HttpServletRequest request;
    @Context
    ServletContext ctx;

    @GET
    @Path("/getJustAdministrators")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Collection<Administrator> getJustAdministrators() {
        System.out.println("get administrators");
        return getAdministrators().getValues();
    }

    private Administrators getAdministrators() {
    Administrators administrators = (Administrators) ctx
            .getAttribute("administrators");
    if (administrators == null) {
        administrators = new Administrators(ctx.getRealPath(""));
        ctx.setAttribute("administrators", administrators);
    }
    return administrators;
}
```

My main.js file, which is linked to my welcome page, looks like this:

```
var rootURL1 = "../eTicket/rest/service/getJustAdministrators";

loadAdministrators();

function loadAdministrators() {
    console.log('loadAdministrators');
    $.ajax({
        type : 'GET',
        url : rootURL1,
        dataType : "json", // data type of response
        success : function(data) {
            alert(data);
        }
    });
}
```

And i get error in 'inspect' like this:

http://localhost:8080/eTicket/rest/service/getJustAdministrators 404 (Not Found)

My web.xml file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
  <display-name>eTicket</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>start.html</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
  <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>eTicket</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Why it can't find my resource method??

Comment: But it succesfully logs 'loadAdministrators' to console...

Answer (score 0):

Your sub-path may be trying to bind to the root, just like /service is.

```
@Path("/getJustAdministrators")
```

You may want:

```
@Path("getJustAdministrators")
```

Or:

```
@Path("./getJustAdministrators")
```

Or even more explicitly:

```
@Path("/service/getJustAdministrators")
```

Comment: Also my service class is underneath 'eTicket' package which is underneath 'src' in my 'eTicket' project...

Comment: If you just put a @Get at the top-level (/service) and have it do something, can it even find that?

Comment: It cannot even find that... GET http://localhost:8080/eTicket/rest/service 404 (Not Found)

Comment: It is possible var rootURL1 = "../eTicket/rest/service/getJustAdministrators" does not do what you think. You may just want var rootURL1 = "/eTicket/rest/service/getJustAdministrators";  Finally, wondering if eTicket is really existing in the path, or if the root of your site is just going to put everything under localhost.../rest/..etc. So you can try combinations with and without eTicket in the path and see.

Answer (score 0):

The definition of your servlet class is not correct:

```
<servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
```

It should be pointing to your Service.java class.

Please use this page as reference:

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs92/webapp/configureservlet.html

Comment: Are you sure? because i have one project that works with glassfish and there is everything analogically same as mine but my doesnt work...

Comment: I haven't explicitely tested but it makes logical sense. You need to tell your applet what service to use on the /eTicket/rest endpoint. Have you tried? How else would glassfish know to use your Service.java class when a client tried to consume that endpoint.